# Firebase Cloud Functions: Keeping things in sync

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have users and companies and want to store a company for each user and all of the users of each company in Firebase.

```
user={
  "id":"tjkdEnc3skdm2Jjknd"
  "name":"Adam",
  "street":"Sideway 4",
  "company":"dHend4sdkn25"
}

companies={
  "id":"dHend4sdkn25",
  "name":"Comp Ltd.",
  "members":[
      {
      "id":"tjkdEnc3skdm2Jjknd"
      "name":"Adam"
      },{
      "id":"dfjnUkJKB3sdn8n2kj"
      "name":"Berta"
      }
  ]
}
```

All explanations say that duplicate data is the best way to deal with and so I want to write some cloud functions to keep thigs in sync when editing on one of the sides.
Basically I started with

```
exports.userChangedCompany = functions.firestore
.document('users/{userId}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const data = change.after.data();
  const previousData = change.before.data();

  if (data.company == previousData.company) {
    return null;
  }
   else{
    admin.firestore().doc('companies/'+data.company).set({ ... });
   } 
  });
```

to update the companies when a user changed the company. Unfortunately I haven't found any hint how to set the new company-data properly.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you please share screenshot of all sample documents? Like 1 company and 1 user and then explain? "company for each user and all of the users of each company" kind of unclear to me

Comment: I added some sample structure. Basically it's about keeping duplicate content in different collections in sync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to remove user from `members` array of old company and add in that array of new company. You just need IDs of both companies.

```js
async function updateCompanies(userId, username, oldCompanyId, newCompanyId) {
  const companiesRef = await admin.firestore().collection("companies")
  const userObj = {id: userId, name: username}
  
  // Removing from old company and adding in new company
  await Promise.all([ 
    companiesRef.doc(oldCompanyId).update({members: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(userObj)}),
    companiesRef.doc(newCompanyId).update({members: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(userObj)})
  ])
  return true
}
```

You can just call this function in your cloud function. Just make sure you pass correct params. The reason why you need to pass the username as well is you have array of objects (members) and hence you need the complete object to add/remove using `arrayUnion/arrayRemove`.

Comment: Thanks! this works perfect when the memberships are inside the company object. Can you please also help me if the memberships are in a subcollection? (maybe this structure is more flexible for the future)

Comment: @bastifix sure happy to help but that might be irrelevant to this question but anyway can you share the update structure with subcollections?. You got Discord?